# Datepicker Position not fixed with textfield in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a Fancy Box Popup. In which I have a long Content. That content includes a Date of Birth Field with Datepicker.

Now when I click in field Calender appears but it doesnot remains with the textfield when I scroll with my mouse wheel, the datepicker doesnot moves , its remains on the same place where it was opened, i want it to move with the scroll.

```
Here is the FIDDLE DEMO with this issue :
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1314/

Just click on Popup and then click in Textfield, and then scroll it,

How can I fix this ?

Comment: actually datepicker position is fixed and its in same place the inside fancybox items only moving

Comment: Try changing the .ui-datepicker in the css file. Should do the trick.

Comment: Here is something that fit's some of your needs. `http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1319/` however note that we are fiddling with the default functionality, so further customizations will be needed.

Comment: This fiddle is not working properly, the positioning issue is fixed but the date is not being picked and also its not hidding after clicking somewhere else on page

Comment: @CodeHunter Did you try my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19820936/297641

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `datapicker` positions the calendar based on `input` original position. However, it doesn't reposition when you scroll. However you could reposition the `datepicker` on fancybox `scroll`.

```
afterLoad: function () {
    $('.fancybox-inner').on('scroll', function () {
        var inp = $(this).find('input.hasDatepicker');
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('top', inp.offset().top + inp.outerHeight());
    });
}, beforeClose: function () {
    $('.fancybox-inner').off('scroll');
}
```

`afterLoad` and `beforeClose` are callback methods triggered by fancy box after loading the fancy box and before closing the box.

Check out the demo http://jsfiddle.net/NsNHZ/1/ and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is the **`default position`** of datepicker is **`fixed`** and hence there is movement when you scroll.

It won't be nice to fix a datepicker along with textbox.  I would suggest 2 options

1. Better remove the scroll in the popup ([**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1317/)).
2. Make a inline datepicker ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1316/))

Comment: Issue is not fixed in your answer fiddle

Comment: @CodeHunter check my 1 fiddle

Comment: Removing scroll is not an option, because i have to keep it in my orignal content

Answer (score 0):

please used `position: fixed;` and `margin-top:40px;`

Comment: I guess CSS is not a solution here

Answer (score 0):

If I where you, I would just close the DatePicker on scroll and on resize, probably no one would mind, since it also closes `onblur()`

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1325/

```
$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    },
    afterLoad: function () {
        $('.fancybox-inner').on('scroll', function () {
            CloseDatePicker();      
        });
    }, beforeClose: function () {
        $('.fancybox-inner').off('scroll');
    }
});

$(function() {
    $( "#dateofbirth" ).datepicker();

    /*Load only inside fancybox*/
    $(window).resize(function(){
        CloseDatePicker();
    });
});

function CloseDatePicker()
{
      if($("#dateofbirth").datepicker( "widget" ).is(":visible"))
      {
          $("#dateofbirth").datepicker("widget").hide();
          $("#dateofbirth").trigger( "blur");          
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set orientation js bootstrap
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#orientation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30063341)

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether this fiddle works or not - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1328/).

```
 $('#dateofbirth').focus(function(){
     $( ".a" ).show();
     $( ".a" ).datepicker();
     });
     $('#dateofbirth').blur(function(){
     $( ".a" ).hide();
     });
```

Changed html:-

```
 <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">
 <div class='a'></div> // new div added
```